# Is my old bike safe?

Tags: maintenance, carbon, aluminum

The old bike is a Cannondale R-600 purchased in 1999.

- Original key components. Frame, fork. (Aluminum frame, carbon fork)
- Ridden for several thousand miles.
- Well maintained. (Various parts have been replaced and upgraded over time.)
- A few visible minor dings here and there.

Question: Is the frame/fork safe? I can sell it or trash it.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think the bike is *un*-safe?

Comment: @ Neil Fein - Only reason in thinking that the bike is unsafe - Read a recent article on how carbon components may deteriorate. That's all.

Comment: Why are people downvoting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it were a steel frame and fork there would be no question -- steel lasts nearly forever, even when moderately rusty, and can take all sorts of abuse.

Aluminum is a bit less robust, but if it only has "a few thousand" miles on it (and not 30,000) and has not been abused (or hit by a car) then it should be good.  The problem with aluminum is that it can develop hidden cracks, but you've given us no reason to suspect that of this bike.

The carbon fork is also less robust than steel, and can develop hidden cracks.  But again, unless there's something in its history to make it suspect then it should be fine.

Certainly age is not a problem.  Nothing really "ages" on a bike beyond the tires (and, to a slight extent, the lubes).  (It could be true that the carbon fiber will deteriorate after 50 years or so, but that's something for your grandchildren to worry about.)

Frankly, I'm a little curious as to why you're concerned.

Comment: Daniel - See above - Not steel at all.

Comment: @none - someone goes out of their way to write a comprehensive answer to your request and you call them an idiot. Folks here are usually polite and helpful and don't resort to name calling.

Comment: @none - I said "*If* it were a steel frame and fork ..."

Answer (score 5):

Do you know the history of the bicycle (crashed, etc)?

While bicycle geometry\components\preferences have changed over the last 12 years, the life span of well cared for aluminum frame and carbon fork are much longer.

Clean the frame and fork and give it a thorough examination.  Look for:

1. Major dents in the frame that may compromise the integrity (minor dents and dings are fine).
2. Cracks or cracking at the frames weld points.
3. Abrasions or cracks in the carbon (even minor abrasions can over time weaken the integrity of the fork).

If in doubt drop by your local bike shop and have them inspect it.

Comment: Have you actually read any of the good answers provided to you?

Comment: I'm not following why you commented that under my post.

Answer (score 3):

Unless there are cracks or heavy rust, you should be good.

Pictures of the dings? If they are deep enough to cause metal fatigue, you might have an issue but I doubt you would call it a "ding" at that point.

Happy Riding!

Comment: Also. The fork is carbon and 12+ years old. I keep reading how carbon components may be subject to catastrophic failure.